# Capture exclamation mark before " and ( but not inside "" (RegEx)

Tags: regex, language-agnostic, regex-negation

How do you capture an exclamation mark `!` before `"` and `(`, but not inside two double quotes `"`?

Before prerequisity is ok, but latter part, that exclamation mark should not be inside doubles quotes, should be added:

```
\s*([\!])\s*(")|\s*([\!])\s*(\()
```

Given input: `( !   "A"   !   (!"B" "C" "   ! ( "))`

Expected output: `( ! "A" ! ( ! "B" "C" "   ! ( "))`

http://www.regexr.com/3f495

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correct, so you want to have exactly **one space around exclamation marks outside of quotes**.

this regex should do the job:

```
\G[^"]*?\K(?:\s*!\s*(?=["(]))([^"!]*(?:"[^"]*")?)
```

you can find an explanation of the regex here:

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Debuggex Demo](https://www.debuggex.com/r/m9VTisuidQqH_lFU)

and for substituion you can take a look here: 
https://regex101.com/r/dzwTUp/1

Comment: regex101 example works as expected, I'm not sure about debuggex how it should work, but it has a very nice interface for regex programmers!

Comment: @MarkokraM yes, exactly for the good interface ... currently for some reasons the image generator seems to be broken